# Using underscore to determine if an object exists in a deeply nested array of objects?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

This comparison is a bit odd as I have the following format:

#### Preferences Object:

```
{ 
  models: [
   {... attributes: {} },
   {... attributes: {} },
   {... attributes: {} }
  ]
}
```

#### Data Array:

```
[{}, {}, {}]
```

I have this `object` that contains an `array` of *more* `objects` with a key called ***attributes***.

#### My Goal:

My goal is to see which items in the ***Data Array*** don't exist as the value to the attributes key in the models array using Underscore.JS.

#### Hacky Attempt:

This is definitely not how I want to code this, but `localStorageLayers` is the **Data Array** and the `layerPrefs` is the **Preferences Object** is the above labelling.

```
_.each(localStorageLayers, (localLayer) => {
    var layerWasLoaded = false;
    _.each(layerPrefs.models, (layerPref) => {
        if (_.isEqual(layerPref.attributes, localLayer)) {
            layerWasLoaded = true;
            // Don't do anything
        }
    })
    if (layerWasLoaded == false) {
        // Do stuff
    }
})
```

Comment: I don't understand. What is your question?

Comment: @KenrySanchez I've updated the OP. I want to see which items in the data array are never a value to any of the "attributes" keys in the models array of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `filter` the `localStorageLayers` down to a subset where the `localLayer` is found to be equal to none (negated `some`) of the `layerPrefs.models` objects as compared to its `attributes` property.

I don't use `lodash`, but `result` should contain only the `localStorageLayers` that did not find equality in `layerPrefs.models`.

```js
const layerPrefs = { 
  models: [
   {attributes: {foo: "foo"} },
   {attributes: {foo: "bar"} },
   {attributes: {baz: "baz"} }
  ]
};

const localStorageLayers = [
  {foo: "foo"}, {hot: "dog"}, {hot: "dog"}, {baz: "baz"}
];

const result = _.filter(localStorageLayers, localLayer => 
    !_.some(layerPrefs.models, layerPref =>
        _.isEqual(layerPref.attributes, localLayer)
    )
);

console.log(result);

// Remove duplicates
const noDupes = _.uniqBy(result, _.isEqual);

console.log(noDupes);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

---

You could reverse the evaluation of each `localLayer` by doing `_.every` with `!_.isEqual`.

Use which ever seems clearer.

```
const result = _.filter(localStorageLayers, localLayer => 
    _.every(layerPrefs.models, layerPref =>
        !_.isEqual(layerPref.attributes, localLayer)
    )
);
```

Comment: Do I need to return the isEqual? This doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: The `isEqual` is returned from the arrow function automatically because I removed the curly braces. As to why it doesn't work, I don't know because you didn't supply complete sample data.

Comment: Ah, this is perfect. I was adding curly braces, so needed to return the some and isEqual methods. Thanks so much

Comment: Is it possible to add a duplicate removal in here as well? So I don't return objects into the array if the same object already exists?

Comment: I see that I had missed the removal of a brace too, so I fixed it and added a demo. As to duplicate removal, I'd probably just do something similar with the `result` by filtering down to those that are not equal from the current object forward. I'll add that to my demo.

Comment: Looking at their docs, I found `_.uniqBy`, which filters an array down to a unique set based on the provided predicate. I updated the example to show it working.